# Firebase Analytics Events don't show ad_click and ad_impression events

Tags: ios, firebase, admob, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase event reporting for an iOS app. As stated [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en) ad_click and ad_impression are automatically collected events. I have linked the AdMob app to the Firebase app. I have followed the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7378163) . Firebase Analytics SDK is 5.5.0 and Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK is 7.37. I see ad_click and ad_impression events in Debug View in Firebase Analytics. But I don't see them in Events in Firebase Analytics even after 24 hours. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

These two events can't be exported to BigQuery from Firebase Analytics, which is documented here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=en. Hope this provides the reason.